# Can you set the css class for the div generated by an update panel from the code behind?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

If I have an UpdatePanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udPanel" runat="server">
            ...
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

creates this div when it's rendered

```
<div id="ctl00_udPanel">
```

How do you reference this  in the code behind to change the css class dynamically?

Comment: Heh, you can hack its id out into a style tag: `<style>#<%=udPanel.ClientID%> {/*...*/}</style>`

Comment: You know, you can change the render mode to generate a SPAN instead of a DIV using RenderMode="Inline" if that helps your use case.

Answer (score 4):

What you could do is write out the ClientID client-side within javascript and then use jQuery with an [AddClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/addClass) (*untested*):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#<%=udPanel.ClientID%>").addClass("MyClass");
</script>
```

Comment: probably cleaner to access a normal runat=client element by ID and further to lean on jquery's 'live' method, but in principle clean enough (where a JS requirement is acceptable)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `UpdatePanel` is considered to be an abstraction that is invisible to the browser (but in reality it isn't). So you can't apply a classname to it.

The only way is to apply the classname to a `div` or an ASP.NET `Panel` inside the `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: My problem is the "invisible" update panel is adding space between two controls on my page.  I'd like to use the update panel, but it makes the page ugly.

Answer (score 0):

From the back of my mind, try `udPanel.Attributes`.

Comment: unfortunately, Attributes, Class, CssClass, and Style are not options

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best I could find to do this *dynamically*.  You can create a javascript function to change the css class which accepts the clientID of the control to change and a string for the css class as parameters.  You can set this to be called in the onload() method of the body dynamically passing in the clientID and the css class.  This enables you to change the css class for different states of the page.

```
    HtmlGenericControl body = (HtmlGenericControl)uPanel.Page.Master.FindControl("masterBody");
    body.Attributes.Add("onload", "setCSSClass('" + uPanel.ClientID.ToString() + "', '" + cssClassName + "')");
```